# Does zgrep unzip a file before searching?

Tags: linux, shell, grep, compression, gzip

Does zgrep unzip a gzip file and make a temporary copy before searching or does it search directly on the compressed file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [source](http://ftp.nluug.nl/NetBSD/NetBSD-current/src/usr.bin/gzip/zgrep) of `zgrep` uncompresses the file with `zcat` and pipes the result to `grep`.

So, no, it does not use a temporary file, but yes, it decompresses (but not fully) before searching.

Comment: So does this [other source](https://fossies.org/linux/zutils/zgrep.cc), which is in C++.